# Adding new row to a table using array - question about formula

Tags: excel, vba

I like use following method to insert data into new table row:

```
  ' (...)
  ' prepare table row
    Dim newRowArr(1 To 3) As Variant
            newRowArr(1) = 1 ' sample data
            newRowArr(2) = 2
            newRowArr(3) = 3
  ' inserting row
    Dim newRow As ListRow
        Set newRow = sampleTbl.ListRows.Add
            newRow.Range.Value = newRowArr
```

If I have a table with 4 column and the first three columns contains data and the last column contains formula: **is there a way to copy the formula automatically, or I have to write formula "manually"** in row Range or array?

I can do this using .Formula or .FormulaR1C1, but I'm not sure if it is absolutelly necessary. When I skip newRowArr(4) then in 4th column I get #N/A in the column instead of automatically copying formula. Maybe better is to use .Offset to copy the formula without rewrite it, but I'm looking for the most efficient and "elegant" way to do this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Don't write to the whole row.

```
newRow.Range(1).Resize(, 3).Value = newRowArr
```

Comment: But what about situation when we have 5 columns and the 3rd contains formula? Can we "skip" the middle column and still put our data into new row at once immediately?

Comment: No, you have to loop the array to do that. You can't skip elements of the array if you writing in one step.

Comment: So in the situation when we have data columns well mixed with formulas there's no performance advantage of this array method, or we must put formulas "manually". Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, basically you can't use it, yeah.

Comment: Wouldn't an array be able to hold a formula through `newRowArr(4) = aRef.Formula`. maybe there is room to play with that and therefore "skip" the element? Curious

Comment: Well @JvdV yes, that might be a possibility. I'm not sure what all OP has tried ("I can do this using .Formula or .FormulaR1C1")

Comment: Well the idea is there up for grabs to play around with for OP =)

Comment: Or maybe custom macro to inserting rows with arguments: 1) table 2) data Array 3) optional column indexes. And then (if given) we group indexes and make range using Union. In the end I am not sure if we can fill uncontiguous range in the simple way with array. What do you think? I must try it

Comment: Non-contiguous ranges and arrays don't work well. Well, maybe a jagged array might work.